# What do you do with "the last will and testament"?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

Do you "execute", "carry out" or "fulfil" the last will and testament?

Comment: Those are all synonyms, and in general usage any of them would work.  Are you asking for what language an attorney would use?

Comment: Not at all. It has nothing to do with attorney's language. I am interested in normal/general English case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're alive, you *execute* your last will.

See this page from [LegalZoom](http://info.legalzoom.com/execute-last-testament-20550.html).

> A last will and testament is a document used to distribute the property after the property owner dies. The person who creates the will, known as the testator, must not only clearly state his intended distribution of property, **he must also execute the will** in legally valid form.

After you're dead, your [executor](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/executor) is "a person named in a decedent's will to carry out the provisions of that will." The executor *also* [executes](http://info.legalzoom.com/soon-wills-executed-after-death-4569.html) the will.

> Executing a will, or carrying out the instructions in its text, can begin as soon as the will is filed with the probate court. The will may be filed as soon as the testator, who wrote the will, has passed away.

Here, *executing* is informally called *carrying out* the instructions of the will.

I would choose *execute* for most contexts, as it would be understood through common usage and in legal contexts. Most English speakers would understand if you said "I'm executing my father's last will and testament" or "I'm executor for his estate."

You could say you were *carrying out* his will, but this informal sense may introduce ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

It depends, because it may or may not be a legal document, and if it is, the laws of a particular place might require particular language.

However, in general terms of English language, I would say a person would "follow" the instructions in the document, but other words could be used. The title "last will and testament" really just means "These are my wishes for after my death, written down." So, they can be "carried out," "respected," and so on.

"Execute" has an association with contract law; it would be an appropriate verb in connection with an attorney or executor carrying out instructions, such as to transfer assets, according to a legally binding will.